# Delphi - How to pass a 'Type' as a parameter

Tags: c, delphi, types, parameter-passing

I would like to know if it is possible to pass a declared type (in this case a record) to my function. I would not even ask if it was not for the `SizeOf()` function, because it can take a type as a parameter.

I'm translating code from C and I would like to keep it as close to the original as possible.
The C program declares PushArray and PushStruct as macros. Since Delphi does not have macro support, I'm trying to turn them into functions.

I've googled this a bit and it seems that I could possible use generic types.
Like `function PushStruct<T>(Arena : Pmemory_arena; dtype : <T>)` but you can only use this in an OOP type application.

```
function PushSize_(Arena : Pmemory_arena; Size : memory_index) : pointer;
begin
    Assert((Arena^.Used + Size) <= Arena^.Size);
    Result := Arena^.Base + Arena^.Used;
    Arena^.Used := Arena^.Used + Size;
end;

function PushStruct(Arena : Pmemory_arena; dtype : ?) : pointer;
begin 
    result := PushSize_(Arena, sizeof(dtype));
end;

function PushArray(Arena : Pmemory_arena; Count: uint32; dtype : ?) : pointer;
begin
    result := PushSize_(Arena, (Count)*sizeof(dtype))
end;
```

Here is the original C code:

```
#define PushStruct(Arena, type) (type *)PushSize_(Arena, sizeof(type))
#define PushArray(Arena, Count, type) (type *)PushSize_(Arena, (Count)*sizeof(type))
void *
PushSize_(memory_arena *Arena, memory_index Size)
{
    Assert((Arena->Used + Size) <= Arena->Size);
    void *Result = Arena->Base + Arena->Used;
    Arena->Used += Size;

    return(Result);
}
```

Comment: This kind of thing gives me the willies. Whatever job the whole thing you're translating does, probably should be re-implemented in an object oriented way instead of trying to translate your C code directly.  Why would you want to keep doing all this voodoo pointer math if you don't have to? You really love the way C lets you shoot yourself in the foot in so few lines of code? Maybe you don't even have to translate this entire thing, just transliterate by using a different pattern, a different data structure, use a real data type or object instead of a low level memory buffer hack.

Comment: Dear Warren. 
The code I'm translating is from a educational source that teaches low level voodoo memory buffer access specifically. The author states, that while he knows how to use higher order languages, this low level stuff is a dying art and he is teaching it. Later we will even do some assembly code. So while I know you mean well with your comment, in this case it is not applicable.

Comment: Okay. Glad you are using your powers for good instead of for evil.

Answer (score 5):

The C code isn't passing a type to the function. The pre-processor is expanding the macro and computing the size. You can see that from the prototype of the function:

```
void *PushSize_(memory_arena *Arena, memory_index Size)
```

Since you don't have macros in Delphi, you cannot arrange a direct translation. Personally, if it were me I would not attempt to match the C code exactly. I'd pass the size and leave it to the caller to use `SizeOf`. I don't think that's a terrible burden. It still leaves you with something very close to a literal translation – all you are missing is the convenience macros.

If you wanted to use generics, you could do so, but it would require you to use a static method. For instance:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
    class function PushSize(Arena: Pmemory_arena; Size: memory_index): Pointer; static;
    class function PushStruct<T>(Arena: Pmemory_arena): Pointer; static;
  end;
....
class function TMyClass.PushSize(Arena: Pmemory_arena; Size: memory_index): Pointer;
begin
  Result := ....;
end;

class function TMyClass.PushStruct<T>(Arena: Pmemory_arena): Pointer;
begin
  Result := PushSize(Arena, SizeOf(T));
end;
```

If you want to return a typed pointer that would look like this:

```
type
  TMyClass<T> = class
    type P = ^ T;
    class function PushSize(Arena: Pmemory_arena; Size: memory_index): Pointer; static;
    class function PushStruct(Arena: Pmemory_arena): P; static;
  end;
....
class function TMyClass<T>.PushSize(Arena: Pmemory_arena; Size: memory_index): Pointer;
begin
  Result := ....;
end;

class function TMyClass<T>.PushStruct(Arena: Pmemory_arena): P;
begin
  Result := PushSize(Arena, SizeOf(T));
end;
```

Obviously you'd know what name to use instead of `TMyClass`!

I'm not convinced that generics are a good fit here because I guess you are wanting as literal a translation as possible. I would not choose to use generics in this scenario.

Comment: You are probably right. Do you have any idea how sizeOf works? Since there is not actual declaration I can find in System.pas, I'm curious on how it would be declared.

Comment: It's a compiler intrinsic, so there is no source for the function because it's not evaluated at runtime. The compiler knows what the type is, knows its size, and can evaluate the function at compile time. So `SizeOf(T)` is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

You could "expand the macros" by simply declaring your own Push* funtions for each record type as needed:

```
type
  // just guessing here...
  PMemoryArena = ^TMemoryArena;
  TMemoryArena = record
    Base: Pointer;
    Used: Cardinal;
    Size: Cardinal;
  end;
  TMemoryIndex = Cardinal;
  // 1st example record type
  PMyRecord1 = ^TMyRecord1;
  TMyRecord1 = record
    I1: Integer;
    I2: Integer;
  end;
  // 2nd example record type
  PMyRecord2 = ^TMyRecord2;
  TMyRecord2 = record
    D1: Double;
    D2: Double;
  end;

function PushSize_(Arena: PMemoryArena; Size: TMemoryIndex): Pointer; inline;
begin
  Assert(Arena^.Used + Size <= Arena^.Size);
  Result := Pointer(NativeUInt(Arena^.Base) + Arena^.Used);
  Inc(Arena^.Used, Size);
end;

function PushMyRecord1(Arena: PMemoryArena): PMyRecord1;
begin
  Result := PMyRecord1(PushSize_(Arena, SizeOf(TMyRecord1)));
end;

function PushMyRecord2(Arena: PMemoryArena): PMyRecord2;
begin
  Result := PMyRecord2(PushSize_(Arena, SizeOf(TMyRecord2)));
end;
```

Comment: I have thought about that. It will be even better to use function overloading so you can keep using the same function name.

Comment: Good idea but then you have to use procedures with an out parameter because overloaded functions may not differ by return type only (that wouldn't compile). So you could have procedures like: `procedure PushStruct(Arena: PMemoryArena; out Struct: PMyRecord1); overload; procedure PushStruct(Arena: PMemoryArena; out Struct: PMyRecord2); overload; ` etc.

Comment: Yes, that is how I ended up implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem kind of unnecessary.

why not, for example

```
function PushStruct(Arena : Pmemory_arena) : pointer;
begin 
    result := PushSize_(Arena, sizeof( Arena ));
end;
```

Comment: Well, if you look closely, the asker wants to call with different values of the size. Also, you know that sizeof(Arena) is just the size of a pointer?

Comment: Yes, David - my mistake.